# How to track action performed on web view content UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, uwp

I have a WebView in UWP which is getting some html content (including javascript).
I need a way to track actions performed on the Webview content, for instance if the user has clicked a button I would like to know.

I know https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify
but for this to work javascript has to call `window.external.notify()`.

But the problem is that I don't own this content and it doesn't make sense to ask the owners to change their handler to publish this `window.external.notify()`.

So, is there any way I can track all the user actions without modifiying the content?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish what you're wanting to do with the UWP web viewer.

One alternative to consider is [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) which has a WPF implementation of Chromium.

It gives you a lot of hooks and handlers to intercept requests and do a lot of custom work on JavaScript that you don't control. I used it to build a WPF based help system and it allowed me to intercept links to PDFs and videos so that I could display them in special viewers.

Comment: Just saw this answer... UWP does not support WPF... so no go. maybe try [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationstarting?view=winrt-19041](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationstarting?view=winrt-19041) to intercept and cancel navigation events...